# jQuery horizontal list slider - LavaLamp

Tags: jquery, css, slider, lavalamp

I've been trying to recreate the "Budget" slider from the Hitmo website:
http://hitmo-studio.com/contact.html#budget-panel-container

But I can't get it running as smoothly as the Hitmo slider:
http://jsfiddle.net/XNBMr/1/

Things I need:

- Smoother animation
- Change the color of the text when "current" to white (no text-shadow) addClass on a tag?
- "Choose budget" shouldn't be selectable
- Allow "Blue box" to move when option has been clicked (won't move whilst still hovering)
- When hovering away from the blue box then back over it, the hover style below flashes through

I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this. I feel it's very close but I know there must be a more streamlined approached, and I want this to be as simple as possible. Thanks!

Comment: http://nixboxdesigns.com/projects/jquery-lavalamp/demos/original.html#Ride.. you do view source and get the all code?

Comment: No I got all the code the download. I changed it so the slider doesn't move until it's clicked. $li.not(".back").click(function() {

Comment: if u use  $li.click(function(e) {
                 move(curr); and remove hover. it works for doubleclick

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to work using single click

Comment: what if you use this? http://www.queness.com/post/530/simple-lava-lamp-menu-tutorial-with-jquery. just change $('#lava li').hover(function () { to $('#lava li').click(function () {

Comment: you can even set var style = 'easeOutElastic'; to different effect from jquery easing plugin js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us see:

- Animation: You probably want "easeout" which starts fast, and slows down.
- White Text & Hover: Adding a class is pretty simple (but I worry about that css, it is not really created for performance; see [vanseodesign](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-selector-performance/) or [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Writing_Efficient_CSS)).  I also removed a little of the waist but it really should be dropped and redone (it is pretty rough).
- Click & Budget: ummm, basic jquery events (I take it you found the code and tried to modify it); and preventing the budget from getting re-selected is just a simple conditional...

[-- DEMO --](http://jsfiddle.net/scispear/6jtYx/)

Comment: Thanks SciSpear! That's working how I hoped it would. I'll redo the CSS as it's just a mash-up at the moment.